# Batch File How to not print final space in a vbscript

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, vbscript

I have a question about something I've been trying to figure out for at least a good hour.
I have a batch file that creates a small VBS script so that I can do some complex calculations (well, at least some that the command prompt won't do).
The code is super simple

```
set /p APERTURE=Please enter f/stop aperture:
(
echo Wscript.Echo "Calculated APEX Value: ",round^(^(log^(%APERTURE%^)*^(2.0/log^(2.0^)^)*62500^)^),"/62500"
) >%temp%\calculate.vbs
cscript //nologo %temp%\calculate.vbs
```

but there is a small problem that annoys me to no end. The result shows as

`Calculated APEX Value: 432429 /62500`

when I really want it to show as

`Calculated APEX Value: 432429/62500`

Notice the space between the numbers.

This script runs on the latest version of Windows 10 (upgraded last night).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of wScript.echo's parameters. As soon as you use multiple parameters, it puts spaces between each result. You need to remove those and put everything in the first parameter. By changing the , for a & (needs escaped due to cmd use) all becomes one parameter and the spaces are gone.

The script becomes as follows:

```
set /p APERTURE=Please enter f/stop aperture:
(
echo Wscript.Echo "Calculated APEX Value: "^&round^(log^(%APERTURE%^)*^(2.0/log^(2.0^)^)*62500^)^&"/62500"
) >%temp%\calculate.vbs
cscript //nologo %temp%\calculate.vbs
```

Comment: That simple?
When I think I racked my brain last night trying to find a workaround...
At 3am I was even going to the point of trying to use the clipboard (though that would be a super cool feature)...

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that simple. At first I thought the output of the calculation used a space, so I started putting a mid(calc,0,4) in there to see if it would trim down, and it did, but with the space in tact. Then I knew it was something on a deeper level. Once I changed the echo's , to a &, it was working. :)

Comment: I know I definitely couldn't figure it out. Thing is I'm not very good at VBscript. OK, I should say I don't know a thing about it and usually just throw code at a file until something doesn't give me an error. But since this morning I've used the bit of code you helped with and threw in a few workarounds using the clip.exe program to make the result also available as a cut & paste solution too. I'm definitely very happy with how it turns out. Now my program returns the proper values for use in an EXIF tag.

Comment: Nice. :) Yeah, my experience is definitely at a high level, which does help tremendously. :)

Comment: I used to be pretty good at the classic VB, but then Microsoft pulled the plug on that. So I ended up going back to classic batch files for a lot of stuff...

Comment: May I recommend you to look into powershell then? It is a really strong language once you understand it, simpler than vb stuff but just as powerful. It would be very easy to do this in powershell too

Comment: And PowerShell ISE makes it so much easier to program in than any other script language. You can just select a bit of code, execute just that, then use the terminal to play with what you just executed to test stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment exchange and to give you an idea on how easy and powerful powershell is, here is your script written in powershell:

```
$aperture = read-host -Prompt "Please enter f/stop aperture"

$APEX = [math]::Round([math]::log($aperture)*(2/[math]::log(2))*62500)

$return = "Calculated APEX Value: $APEX/62500"
set-clipboard -Value $return
write-host $return
```

Comment: Does look pretty simple. I never really thought of using Powershell. But it would be a heck of a job to convert the rest of the massive script that this snippet is a part of...

Comment: Might be a fun project to get you fully into Powershell though. It is very easy if you have a programming background. :)

Comment: Well... my programming background is learning Basic on both a Commodore 64 and an Apple II  :-)  So I guess it shouldn't be hard...

Comment: Ah, Yeah I did learn Basic from the Commodore 64 too. Was my first programming language. Went to QBasic and then QB before going to Visual Basic, only then VBScript... but Batch programming was learned somewhere in between and now php and powershell, and the last two are definitely my preferred languages. For any assignment, I would never go for vbscript anymore. Powershell is so nice.

Answer (score 0):

- Just a few suggestions...

---

Remove all escaping **`^`** replacing `echo` by `set /p`

Use one `label` in `:loop` with `findstr regex` to test input/numbers

Replace `//nologo` to `| find "string"` and get time to delete your `file.vbs` after run

---

```all-filebat
@echo off

:loop
set APERTURE=<nul & <con: set /p APERTURE=Please enter f/stop aperture: 
<con: call echo\%APERTURE%|findstr [0-9] >nul || cls && echo\ && goto=:loop

>"%temp%\calculate.vbs" <nul set /p "'=Wscript.Echo "Calculated APEX Value: "&round((log(%APERTURE%)*(2.0/log(2.0))*62500))&"/62500""
cscript "%temp%\calculate.vbs" | find "APEX" & 2>nul del /q /f "%temp%\calculate.vbs
```

Comment: A bit more convoluted... I think I'll stick to the simple one.

Comment: @Flaver-D Well, thank for comment...

Comment: While it's always fun to get code to jump through hoops, I tend to stick to my old 8bit computing roots when it comes to programming. Not that your solution wouldn't work (it would definitely do the job), but I often think in terms of optimizing operations. Back when you had only a few Kb's of memory, you had to do that. I feel that optimization is an art that is getting lost nowadays. I remember having a poster of the Laws of Computing. One of them was to Keep things simple AND legible. That's what I strive to do.

Comment: @Flaver-D Why did you use (keeps doing) FOTRAN, in my case, keeping things simple is very difficult, especially when working with fixed form in FORTRAN, but having a simple code is something different from having it reliable, which in turn is completely different to have a code that "works".

Comment: @Flaver-D For scientific bases, the simple method does not have a workplace that
 answers how the cosmos dynamically evolves over time, if it had, art would elude the peaceful citizen, using less than 640KB. Keeping a code simple is very easy, it is difficult for the same code to be reliable and safe, where it works is less than the adjectives that qualify it.

Comment: @Flaver-D If my suggestion makes you uncomfortable in any way, let me know and I'll remove it. Again, let me thank you for the comment...

Comment: Oh No, please leave it there! While it might not be the solution I was looking for, it is a very worthwhile addition to the thread. You never know if someone can't find a solution to another problem using that snippet of code. I for one always find it interesting to see what others have come up with (which, when I'm looking for something, is sometimes more adapted to what I'm doing than the preferred solution).